# list does not update after deletes the angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

after I click the button to delete the list does not update, the data is deleted from the database, only after I do an update on the page is the list updated.

code html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Administrador</th>
                        <th>Login</th>
                        <th>Remover</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios | filter: global.search">
                        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td><a ng-href="#/edita/usuario/{{usuario._id}}">{{usuario.nome}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.administrador}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.login}}</td>
                        <td><button ng-click="removeUser(usuario)" class="btn-link"><i style="float: right;" class="icon-remove"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

controller angular:

```
$scope.removeUser = function(usuario){

    var confirmar = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir usuário?");

    if(confirmar == true){
        Usuario.delete({id: usuario._id},
            buscaUsuarios(),
            function(erro){
                console.log("Não foi possível remover usuário.");
                console.log(erro);
            });
    }
    console.log(usuario);
};
```

controller node:

```
controller.removeUsuario = function(req, res){

    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("IDREMOVE "+id);
    Usuario.remove({_id : id}).exec()
        .then(
            function(){
                res.status(204).end();
            },
            function(erro){
                return console.error(erro);
            });

};
```

Thanks..
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is happening because you are not including enough code. However, it seems that you are deleting the user asynchronously trying to pass a success callback handler (buscaUsuarios) and an error handler. Instead of passing the success callback which retrieves the new list, however, it looks like you are passing the results of executing it. Try this instead:

```
$scope.removeUser = function(usuario){

    var confirmar = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir usuário?");

    if(confirmar == true){
        Usuario.delete({id: usuario._id},
            buscaUsuarios,
            function(erro){
                console.log("Não foi possível remover usuário.");
                console.log(erro);
            });
    }
    console.log(usuario);
};
```

Comment: GPicazo, it seems that this working now correct the code. What is the difference of using such a test () function or test. Without the parentheses.

Comment: The difference is that without (), you are passing a reference to the callback function which gets executed after the promise is resolved. With (), you are executing the function before calling the delete and passing the results instead of the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I managed to take one more doubt. I'm still new to angujarjs and nodejs.
Stayed the application code I'm doing on github: https://github.com/tiagoeborsanyi/cartic.git
Tomorrow put a new version with the modifications to the code. It is an application for computer product management. This written in nodejs, express, mongoose, mongodb, Express 4.x, angular, bootstrap and jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code, but you're probably not updating the array usuarios in your scope.

Check to make sure you are actually modifying that reference.  Also note that you should modify the reference itself, not replace it with a new array instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello excuse me by incomplete code.I was trying to pass a callback code to return the updated list. Below the elbow that was passing as callback:

```
function buscaUsuarios(){

    Usuario.query(
        function(usuarios){
            $scope.usuarios = usuarios;
        },
        function(erro){
            console.log('Não foi possível obter a lista de usuários.');
            console.log(erro);
        });
};
```